# Building Jenkins with NetBeans errors

Tags: java, netbeans, jenkins

**I try to build Jenkins project with netBeans but have the same problem all the time.... Multiples tests fails during the building of project. I put descriptions of some fails.**

```
Running hudson.cli.ConnectionMockTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.138 sec - in hudson.cli.ConnectionMockTest
Running hudson.cli.ConnectionTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.14 sec - in hudson.cli.ConnectionTest
Running hudson.cli.PrivateKeyProviderTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.655 sec <<< FAILURE! - in hudson.cli.PrivateKeyProviderTest
initializationError(hudson.cli.PrivateKeyProviderTest)  Time elapsed: 0.015 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name hudson.cli.CLI. Reason: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:207)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:145)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:65)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:439)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:420)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3508)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3497)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3402)
    at org.junit.internal.MethodSorter.getDeclaredMethods(MethodSorter.java:52)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClass.getAnnotatedMethods(TestClass.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateTestMethods(MethodValidator.java:71)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateStaticMethods(MethodValidator.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateMethodsForDefaultRunner(MethodValidator.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.validate(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:108)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:144)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:39)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:217)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  PrivateKeyProviderTest.initializationError » IllegalState Failed to transform ...

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Reactor Summary:

Jenkins main module ............................... SUCCESS [1.996s]
Jenkins CLI ....................................... FAILURE [11.240s]
Jenkins core ...................................... SKIPPED
Jenkins war ....................................... SKIPPED
Test harness for Jenkins and plugins .............. SKIPPED
Jenkins plugin POM ................................ SKIPPED
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 15.449s
Finished at: Mon Oct 06 09:14:39 EDT 2014
Final Memory: 25M/471M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project cli: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Users\ystavcha\Desktop\newClone\jenkins\cli\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to Powermock version. Try upgrading the version.